# Reconciling antd import with postcss

Tags: webpack, less, antd, postcss, postcss-loader

I am trying to use `postcss-env-function` in order to be able to share variables between javascript and less/css. I get the following error during build. The error disappears if I remove the first line of **index.less**:

`@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';`

However, then I will not get antd's styles. (There is no error also if I remove `postcss-loader`). How to solve this issue?

[Minimal repository](https://github.com/abstractifier/postcss-antd)

---

**Error**:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/index.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[2]!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[3]!./src/styles/index.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) postcss-env-fn: <css input> Unknown word

> 1 | opacity=45
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

function buildConfig(args) {
  var rootConfig = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'app.[fullhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
    },
    devtool: (args && args.production ? false : 'inline-cheap-source-map'),
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      disableHostCheck: true,
      hot: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: `https://${process.env.API_HOST}:8081`,
          secure: false,
        }
      },
      https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY_FILE),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT_FILE),
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(c|le)ss$/,
          use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
            { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: { 'postcss-env-function': { importFrom: { environmentVariables: { '--test': '200px' } } } }
              } } },  
            { loader: 'less-loader', options: { lessOptions: { javascriptEnabled: true } } },
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|jpeg)$/,
          use: [
            { loader: 'file-loader' },
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: require('html-webpack-template'),
        devServer: (args && args.production) ? undefined : `https://${process.env.BUBI_API_HOST}:8080`,
        meta: [
          {
            name: 'og:title',
            content: 'frontend-react'
          },
          {
            name: 'og:description',
            content: 'React app'
          },
        ],
        mobile: true,
        lang: 'en-GB',
        title: 'frontend-react',
        scripts: [
        ],
      }),
      new CopyPlugin([
        { from: 'static_assets/', to: '' },
      ]),
    ],
  };

  if (args && args.production) {
    rootConfig = {
      ...rootConfig,
      optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
          extractComments: 'all',
        })],
        usedExports: true,
      },
    };
  }

  return rootConfig;
}

module.exports = buildConfig;
```

**Versions**:
less-loader: 8.1.1  postcss: 8.3.5  postcss-loader: 6.1.1

Beginning of **index.less**:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less'; 

@shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
@body-background-color: #f7fafc;

.text {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  background-color: @body-background-color;
  padding: 0; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**package.json**:

```
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.jpeg';
declare module '*.png';
```

**.babelrc**:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Comment: please share the index.less file and webpack, used loaders versions, etc. package.json if possible

Comment: @nickbullock I added them.

Comment: Why does your `package.json` file have typescript definitions in it?

Comment: Also, how do you import the `index.less` file (probably in `/src/index.tsx`)?

Comment: @Domi I have two tsx files containing import ```'./index.less'```, and two less files containing ```@import '../index.less'```

Comment: @Domi I added a link to a minimal repository.

Comment: @mikael The official `antd` documentation recommends use with `CRA` - have you confirmed that that works? And if so, does it use the same versions of the libraries  and tools involved (such as `webpack`) - can you check the `{yarn.,package-}lock` file? The official documentation says nothing about which webpack or loader versions should be used. There is potential for disaster there.

Comment: Also what happens if you remove  `postcss-env-function`? What happens if you only remove  `environmentVariables` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your compiled CSS contains `filter: alpha(opacity=45);` which `postcss-env-function` doesn't like.

The "Unknown word" exception is thrown by `postcss-values-parser` (`postcss-env-function` uses it to parse CSS declaration values).

Ideally, in your case, you'd pass the `ignoreUnknownWords` option to `postcss-values-parser` to ignore that `filter: alpha` declaration, but `postcss-env-function` doesn't let you do that.

So, a possible solution could be to modify `postcss-env-function` so you can pass the `ignoreUnknownWords` option to the parser.

Another possible solution could be to remove all the `filter: alpha(opacity=#)` declarations from your CSS since only IE8 and below support it. You can do that, for example, by creating a simple function "plugin" that walks through all the `filter:` declarations and removes it if its value starts with "alpha":

**webpack.config.js:**

```js
{ loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {
  postcssOptions: {
    ident: 'postcss',
    plugins: [
      root => root.walkDecls('filter', decl => {
        if (decl.value.startsWith('alpha')) decl.remove();
      }),
      { 'postcss-env-function': { importFrom: { environmentVariables: { '--test': '200px' } } } },
    ],
  }
} },
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. Could you also let me know how I can view the compiled CSS?

Comment: You can compile your src/index.less using the less CLI: `lessc --js src/index.less` Reference: https://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the MiniCssExtractPlugin to extract the CSS from the Webpack bundle: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a syntax error regarding your opacity. The most common styles use objects so that you would declare opacity as:

```
style = {
   opacity:"45%"
}
```

I am not completely sure how less works as I mostly use sass, scss and css, however, I believe your problem is with declaring your opacity as `{opacity=45}` rather than `{opacity:45}`. It would be helpful to post your style code to review the syntax error, but I would start looking there.

Comment: This seems to make sense. However, I do not have such an opacity declaration anywhere. btw, I added a link to a minimal repository.